# Exporting a custom theme from a UI library using Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am creating a custom UI library for work that uses Material-UI. The UI library has a custom theme where I added to the palette object with custom company colors. The theme lives in the UI library, and for elements that live there, I can use the custom colors in makeStyles, but when I try to use the exported theme in the main codebase, the custom colors throw errors in makeStyles.

I believe the issue is I'm not exporting the theme's custom module. I am unsure how to export and import this correctly into the main codebase.  Currently, I am only exporting the theme file and importing it into the main codebase.

**Main Codebase**:

```
import { theme } from 'customUILibrary';
...
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    ...
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

**CustomUILibrary**:

index.ts:

```
export { theme } from 'theme/theme';
```

theme/theme.ts

```
import {
    createTheme,
    responsiveFontSizes,
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import './extendPalette';

export const theme = responsiveFontSizes(createTheme({

    palette: {
        gradients: {
            primary: 'linear-gradient(270deg, #35C7E1 -10.76%, #1A92BD 121.8%)',
            secondary: 'linear-gradient(270deg, #194E94 0%, #317CA6 100%)',
        },
    },
 
}));
```

extendPalette.ts

```
    declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette' {

    export interface PaletteOptions {
        gradients: {
            primary: string
            secondary: string,
        },
    }
    export interface Palette {
        gradients: {
            primary: string
            secondary: string,
        },
    }

}
```

The custom theme attributes work great inside the UI Library with the UI elements, but when imported into the main codebase the custom attributes aren't being picked up, and in fact causing errors.

Answer (score 1):

One can share type augmentations across multiple projects in a monorepo by putting the types in a .d.ts file somewhere in your workspace and then including it in the `tsconfig.json` for any project that needs these types.

The trick is that you will need to import any interfaces you are augmenting into that file, or else you will override rather than merge the type declarations.

Here is an example from my project setup if it helps:

*<workspaceRoot>/types/mui-types.d.ts*

```js
interface CustomShadowOptions {
  z1: string;
  z4: string;
  z8: string;
  z12: string;
  z16: string;
  z20: string;
  z24: string;
  //
  primary: string;
  secondary: string;
  info: string;
  success: string;
  warning: string;
  error: string;
  //
  card: string;
  dialog: string;
  dropdown: string;
}

import { Theme, ThemeOptions } from '@mui/material/styles';
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Theme {
    customShadows: CustomShadowOptions;
  }
  interface ThemeOptions {
    customShadows?: CustomShadowOptions;
  }
}

import {
  TypeBackground,
  SimplePaletteColorOptions,
  PaletteColor,
} from '@mui/material/styles/createPalette';
declare module '@mui/material/styles/createPalette' {
  interface TypeBackground {
    neutral: string;
  }
  interface SimplePaletteColorOptions {
    lighter: string;
    darker: string;
  }
  interface PaletteColor {
    lighter: string;
    darker: string;
  }
}

import { TypographyVariants } from '@mui/material/styles';
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface TypographyVariants {
    fontWeightSemiBold: React.CSSProperties['fontWeight'];
  }
}

import { ButtonPropsVariantOverrides } from '@mui/material/Button';
declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
  interface ButtonPropsVariantOverrides {
    soft: true;
  }
}

import { ButtonGroupPropsVariantOverrides } from '@mui/material/ButtonGroup';
declare module '@mui/material/ButtonGroup' {
  interface ButtonGroupPropsVariantOverrides {
    soft: true;
  }
}
```

E.G., for a hypothetical app with a shared base config.

*<workspaceRoot>/apps/home/tsconfig.json*

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "files": ["../../types/mui-types.d.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://mui.com/customization/theming/#custom-variables), you can do something like this:

```
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Palette {
    custom: {
      pink: string;
    };
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    custom: {
      pink: string;
    };
  }
}
```

Then you can set you value in theme safely:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    custom: {
      pink: "pink"
    }
  }
});
```

and use it in styles:

```
<Button sx={{ color: "custom.pink" }}>Content</Button>
```

See my [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/customstyles-material-demo-forked-pnvbc?file=/demo.tsx:143-414)

Comment: The custom theme attributes work great inside the UI Library but when imported into the main codebase the custom attributes aren't being picked up, and in fact causing errors.

Comment: You may have to do the `declare module "@mui/material/styles"` where you're using your library, or maybe using a '.d.ts' file in your library package can do the job. I cannot help as i have not access to your code files structure.